# while installing github desktop there is a error log report and can't install

Tags: github, github-desktop

Can anyone suggest the way to solve this issue [image]

```
    2017-11-09 12:31:32> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
2017-11-09 12:31:33> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\joseph_c\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2017-11-09 12:31:33> UpdateManager: using rootAppDirecotry: C:\Users\joseph_c\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams
2017-11-09 12:31:33> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\joseph_c\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams
2017-11-09 12:31:34> CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\joseph_c\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\packages\.betaId'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
```